# Error in while looping in *ngFor in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have the JSON of single object coming as:

[image: JSON Structure]

I achieved this data by calling the API in `component.ts` file which is as follows

```js
/* for auditgorup selecitonm */
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/selections/getAllAuditGroupSelections')
  .subscribe((datas: any[]) => {
    this.auditSelection = datas;
    console.log(this.auditSelection);

    // You'll have to wait that changeDetection occurs and projects data into 
    // the HTML template, you can ask Angular to that for you ;-)
    this.chRef1.detectChanges();

    // Now you can use jQuery DataTables :
    const tables: any = $('#nepal');
    this.dataTable = tables.DataTable();
  });
```

The view is as follows

```html
<table id="nepal" class="table table-bodered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Selection No</th>
      <th>SelectionDate</th>
      <th>SelectedBy</th>
      <th>PanEximNumber</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>PhoneNumber</th>
      <th>SelectionType</th>
      <th>Group Desc</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let nas of auditSelection">
      <td>{{nas.selectionId}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.selectionDate}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.selectedBy}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.panEximNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.name}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.address}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.phoneNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.selectionType}}</td>
      <td>{{nas.assignmentAudit.auditorGroup.groupDesc}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At this last line of `<td>{{nas.assignmentAudit.auditorGroup.groupDesc}}</td>` I cannot get the required value.

The output display should be "g1".

Comment: As per your screenshot, `nas.assignmentAudit` points to an array, so it should be `{nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.groupDesc`

Comment: This will work for you nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.groupDesc

Comment: run Inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to comment, so adding it over here. assignmentAudit is an array, so try accessing using index

Comment: for you can run inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

As per the analysis of the JSON structure  the `assignmentAudit` is an array
so you can only access it with the index positions.

If you are sure the `assignmentAudit` is an array with single value then you can use

```
<td>
  {{nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.groupDesc}}
</td>
```

If `assignmentAudit` has multiple values and is not deterministic you can try

```
<td>
   <span *ngFor="let assignmentAudit of nas.assignmentAudit">
     {{assignmentAudit.auditorGroup.groupDesc}}
   </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nas.assignmentAudit[0].auditorGroup.groupDesc
```

That would work. The section you are trying to access is an array. So picking the first index would then make it defined

Answer (score 0):

`groupDesc` is inside`auditorGroup` loop so you cannot do like to get value inside loop. Try like that.

```
<!-- Angular -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of nas.assignmentAudit.auditorGroup;">

  </li>
</ul>
```

or `<td>{{nas.assignmentAudit.auditorGroup[0].groupDesc}}</td>`